# Sharply $2$-transitive subgroup of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations

My question is about the problem 2.8.14 of the book "Permutation Groups" by Dixon and Mortimer.

Let $F=F_q$ be the finite field with $q$ elements and $d\ge 1$. For each linear transformation $a \in GL_d(F)$ and vector $v\in F^d$, we define the affine transformation $t_{a,v}:F^d\rightarrow F^d$ by $t_{a,v}:u\mapsto ua+v$. Let $AGL_d(F)=\{t_{a,v}: a \in GL_d(F),v\in F^d\}$, the affine group of dimension $d$ over $F$. Suppose that $AGL_d(F)$ act on $F^d$. obviously, the degree of this action is $q^d$.

I want to prove that $AGL_d(F)$ has a sharply $2$-transitive subgroup.

I know that $AGL_d(F)$ is $2$-transitive, but not necessarily sharply $2$- transitive. Also, I know that $AGL_1(F)$ is sharply $2$-transitive. Furthermore, $AGL_d(F)$ has a subgroup that is isomorphic to $AGL_1(F)$ and so, it is sharply $2$-transitive on a subspace of $F_d$, but not on $F_d$. Using these facts, I tried to find the desired subgroup but despite my attempts, I could not make such subgroup.

I will be so grateful for your helpful hints, comments and answers.

Comment: As a hint: a transitive group is sharply $2$-transitive if and only if a point stabiliser acts regularly (sharply $1$-transitively). So, taking the point stabiliser to fix $0$, one might look for a subgroup of the form $N \rtimes H$ where $N = \{t_{1,v} : v \in F^d\}$ and $H \le \mathrm{GL}_d(F)$ is a regular subgroup of order $p^d-1$. Taking $d=1$ you'll get $AGL_1(F) = N \rtimes GL_1(F)$.

Comment: As a further hint, you could take this subgroup to be ${\rm AGL}_1(F_{q^d})$.

Comment: Just by thinking of $F_{q^d}$ as a vector space of dimension $d$ over $F$.

Comment: @DerekHolt: I got the point. Thank you so so much.